# How do you say ‘near my house’

Tags: katakana, hiragana

without using kanji how do you say ‘near my house’ ?

Comment: 'without using kanji' - do you mean a phrase that doesn't use kanji? or you mean that you prefer the answer to be written in kana?

Comment: i mean a phrase that is using hirigana and/ or katakana as i have not learnt kanji yet

Comment: Generally this site is not for simple translations - it is about questions relating to grammar, syntax, etc, etc. So I would suggest that for simple translations you can find good example sentences on jisho.org, for example

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible option for you

> うち　に　ちかい
>
> うち　の　ちかく

Comment: うち の となり is right next to your house (such as your neighbour). If it’s nearby, ちかく is anywhere in general area.

Comment: oooh i see interesting